# NodeJS Datapumps stream from file

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to read a JSON file into a pump (https://www.npmjs.com/package/datapumps). At the moment I'm just trying to print to the console to see if it works however the below doesn't work as it says there's nothing in the buffer. Just need another set of eyes to see where I'm going wrong. The end result is to perform some data transformation and insert into MongoDb.

```
const datapumps = require('datapumps')
const fs = require('fs')

const stream = fs.createReadStream('path-to-file.json')

pump = new datapumps.Pump()
pump.from(stream).run()

console.log(pump.buffer())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```js
const datapumps = require('datapumps');
const fs = require('fs');

const stream = fs.createReadStream('path-to-file.json');

const pump = new datapumps.Pump();

pump.from(stream).run();

const pumpBuffer = pump.buffer();

pumpBuffer.on('sealed', () => {
    const content = pumpBuffer.getContent();
    console.log({ content });
    const oneBuffer = Buffer.concat(content);
    console.log(oneBuffer);
});
```

You can read the data in the form of a buffer and, if necessary, transform it using the built-in Node.js libraries. It will be even simpler because they have complete documentation.